# How To Declare an MKPolygon

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

Ey guys, so a seemingly simple problem but apparently too complicated for me. I am trying to create one instance of MKPolygon and it ain't going too well. Here is the code:

```
MKMapPoint point1 = {38.53607,-121.765793};
 MKMapPoint point2 = {38.537606,-121.768379};
 MKMapPoint point3 = {38.53487,-121.770578};
 NSArray *mapPointArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:point1,point2,point3,nil count:3]; //errors here

 MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:mapPointArr count:3];
```

I am getting a bunch of errors on the line at which I initialize the array(`incompatible type for argument 1`...). Any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MKMapPoint is a plain c-structure and you can't add it to objective-c container directly.

In your case you do not need to do that as  `+polygonWithPoints:` requires not a NSArray, but a c-array as 1st parameter. Proper way to create polygon will be:

```
MKMapPoint points[3] = {{38.53607,-121.765793}, {38.537606,-121.768379}, {38.53487,-121.770578}};
MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:3];
```

Comment: to add it on the map you would do [mapView addOverlay:polygon]; and then implement the viewForOverlay delegate method